# angular 14: Uncaught in promise

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below function

```
  createVersion(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._httpClient
        .post(`${environment.apiUrl}/v1.0/versions`, data, {
          observe: "response",
        })
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
          resolve(response);
        }, reject);
    });
  }
```

When i call it

```
this._versionAddService.createVersion(args).then((result) => {})
```

i get this error

> core.mjs:7640 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): OK
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:31)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167:17)
> at zone.js:1279:17
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26363:33)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
> at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
> at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:35)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:21)
> at invokeTask (zone.js:1600:14)

Comment: Why would you wrap your `Observable` with a `Promise` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers you don't need to wrap it into a promise. RxJs/Observables is heavily used in Angular and often you will just keep as it observable. The benefits are e.g. all the great RxJs operators which makes it easy to do complex data transformations, easy to react to streams of data and then Angular also makes it easy to subscribe and unsubscribe directly in the templates with the async pipe and so on.
The error you see may be because you are missing the catch method (see for createVersion2.)

But here is how you can do it if you want it as a promise:

```
  createVersion(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return firstValueFrom(
      this._httpClient
        .post(`${'environment.apiUrl'}/v1.0/versions`, data, {
          observe: 'response',
        })
        .pipe(catchError((e) => of(`Formatted exception: ${e.error}`)))
    );
  }

  // toPromise() is actually deprecated!
  createVersion2(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return this._httpClient
      .post(`${'environment.apiUrl'}/v1.0/versions`, data, {
        observe: 'response',
      })
      .toPromise()
      .catch((e) => `Formatted exception: ${e.error}`); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RxJS 7 you could use `lastValueFrom` function that will convert your `Observable` to a `Promise`. If you are running on older versions you could use the toPromise(). Careful! This is deprecated in RxJS 7 and in RxJS 8 is going to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use [`HttpClient.post()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post).

Service

```ts
createVersion(data: any): Observable<any> {
  const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/v1.0/versions`;
  const opts = {
    observe: "response",
  };
  return this._httpClient.post(url, data, opts);
}
```

Call it like this.

```
this._versionAddService.createVersion(args).subscribe(resp => {});
```